# Why does my cardview doesn't show correct value for the associated key in the hashmap in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, hashmap, android-cardview

So I have been developing the feature in my app where my cardview flips and show it's back side where it displays the value and on front side of the cardview there is key associated with it. My issue is , the Pair of key-value are not being shown correctly. The value of the key that I have written is not shown but some other value gets shown.Below is my code.

QuestionsFragment.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class QuestionsFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentQuestionsBinding
    lateinit var viewModel: BottomNavigationViewModel

    lateinit var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView

    private val hashMap = HashMap<String,String>()

    private var currentPairIndex =0
    private lateinit var currentPair:Map.Entry<String,String>

    var isFront=true


    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentQuestionsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        bottomNavigationView = (activity as? FirstScreen)?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)!!
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[BottomNavigationViewModel::class.java]

        bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE


        // setting up listener for back Icon
        binding.backIcon?.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }

        binding.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_questionsFragment_to_flashCards)
        }

        //changing color of progress bar progress
        binding.progressHorizontal.progressTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext()
            ,R.color.blue_card))

        //changing color of background color of progress bar
        binding.progressHorizontal.progressBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),
        R.color.silver))

        // Hashmap of strings that will shown on cardview front and back side
        hashMap["What"] = "Kas"
        hashMap["When"] = "Kai"
        hashMap["Where"] = "Kur"
        hashMap["Who"] = "Kas"
        hashMap["Whom"] = "Kam"
        hashMap["Why"] = "Kodėl"
        hashMap["How"] = "Kaip"
        hashMap["Which"] = "Kuris/kuri"
        hashMap["Whose"] = "Kieno"

       val front_animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.anim.front_animator) as AnimatorSet
        val back_animation = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,R.anim.back_animator)as AnimatorSet

        currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)
        binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
        binding.textCardBack.text = hashMap[currentPair.key]

        with(binding) {
            btnFlip.setOnClickListener {
                // initialize currentPairIndex to 0 if it hasn't been initialized yet
                if (currentPairIndex < 0) {
                    currentPairIndex = 0
                }
                if (isFront) {
                    front_animation.setTarget(textCardFront)
                    back_animation.setTarget(textCardBack)
                    front_animation.start()
                    back_animation.start()
                    isFront = false
                    textCardBack.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textCardFront.visibility = View.GONE
                    cardViewQuestions.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.pink))

                } else {

                    textCardFront.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textCardBack.visibility = View.GONE
                    cardViewQuestions.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.blue_card))
                    front_animation.setTarget(textCardBack)
                    back_animation.setTarget(textCardFront)
                    back_animation.start()
                    front_animation.start()
                    isFront = true
                }
                // retrieve the current pair from the hashMap
                currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)
                binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
                binding.textCardBack.text = hashMap[currentPair.key]

                // increment currentPairIndex for the next flip
                currentPairIndex = (currentPairIndex + 1) % hashMap.size
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

so here as you can see , I want to show correct key-value pair like (hashMap["Where"] = "Kur") in which "Where" will be front side of the cardview and "Kur" on back side. The result I am geeting are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're changing the pair every time you click `btnFlip` - you set the front and back text, but whenever you press the flip button, you're setting the text from the **next** pair. So you end up seeing *front 0*, *back 1*, *front 2* etc. because the current index increases each time.

You probably only want to increment `currentPairIndex` when you flip *from the back* round to the front again, I'm guessing. So you get *front 0*, *back 0*, *front 1* and so on. You already have conditional code depending on whether the front or back is showing, you could stick it in there:

```
if (currentPairIndex < 0) {
    currentPairIndex = 0
}

if (isFront) {
    // display data for current card
} else {
    // we're looking at the back, and flip was clicked, so we need the next card
    // This needs to be updated before we use it to get current text etc!
    currentPairIndex = (currentPairIndex + 1) % hashMap.size

    // display data for current card
}

// display data for current card
currentPair = hashMap.entries.elementAt(currentPairIndex)
binding.textCardFront.text = currentPair.key
binding.textCardBack.text = hashMap[currentPair.key]
```

So you're basically only incrementing the index *when the button is clicked*, only when the back is showing, and you update the index before you need to use it - so it needs to happen early.

It might be clearer to make it explicit, separate from the display/animation/flipping code:

```
// handling the current index
if (currentPairIndex < 0) {
    currentPairIndex = 0
}
// advance to the next card if this is flipping from the back
if (!isFront) currentPairIndex = (currentPairIndex + 1) % hashMap.size

// display stuff
```

Comment: It started working :) you are genius ...Thank you so much....